# C++ Error: expected identifier before ‘int’

Tags: c++, list, function, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to write a function, but I get a compiler error. What did I do wrong? If it is something really stupid, I'm sorry. Its late.

Here's the code:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

std::list<std::string> insertinlist(std::list<std::string> listofitems, std::int iterator1, std::string newitem){

list<std::string>::iterator listofitemsiterator = listofitems.begin();
if(iterator1 <= listofitems.size()){
  for(std::size_t i=0; i<iterator1; i++){
    listofitemsiterator++;
  }
  listofitems.insert(listofitemsiterator, newitem);
}else std::cout << "U suck" << std::endl;
return listofitems;

}
```

So yeah... the compiler gives the following error

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 *.cpp -o practice1
In file included from practice1.cpp:6:0:
insertinlist.h:4:78: error: expected identifier before ‘int’
 std::list<std::string> insertinlist(std::list<std::string> listofitems, std::int iterator1, std::string newitem){
                                                                              ^
insertinlist.h:4:82: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘iterator1’
 std::list<std::string> insertinlist(std::list<std::string> listofitems, std::int iterator1, std::string newitem){
                                                                                  ^
insertinlist.h:4:91: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token
 std::list<std::string> insertinlist(std::list<std::string> listofitems, std::int iterator1, std::string newitem){
                                                                                           ^
insertinlist.h:4:105: error: expected initializer before ‘newitem’
 std::list<std::string> insertinlist(std::list<std::string> listofitems, std::int iterator1, std::string newitem){
```

Comment: int is built-in type. It is not in namespace std. And use "using namespace std". This will make your code much clean.

Comment: That is one **expensive** way of inserting an item into a `std::list`

Comment: @RonakPatel `using namespace std;` is generally discouraged here, in favour of explicitly importing those names you actually want (`using std::list;`) or even explicitly qualifying every name like in the question, to avoid the risk of breaking code simply by including another standard library header that has a name clash with something you wrote.

Comment: @WhozCraig how would you do it?

Comment: @hvd agree with you. Also using std::string if you are making more use of string.

Comment: @Landon Something different, to be sure. [See it live](http://ideone.com/r7KCQA)

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah, I fixed it. Don't know if it is best practice, but yeah. http://ideone.com/6nuQgk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is built-in type.  It is not in `namespace std`, simply use `int`, not `std::int`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know. Haha. Just started programming in C++ last week. Thanks for not being a jerk like Moo-juice either.

Comment: @Landon, a jerk?  It was a perfectly valid question!

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem with the code. You knew the answer to your own question. That's called sarcasm. Is it not?